# É possível uma entidade ter 2 relacionamentos N pra N usando Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, migrations

Tenho 2 modelos: `Cliente` e `Empresa`, os quais necessitam ter endereços cadastrados. Criei um outro modelo chamado `Endereço` para fazer os relacionamentos N pra N, no qual ficou desta forma:

```
public class Endereco
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }

        ...

        public ICollection<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Empresa> Empresas {get; set;}
```

Os modelos de `Cliente` e `Empresa` ficaram desta forma:

```
public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Pessoa { get; set; }

        ...

        public ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos{ get; set; }
```

```
public class Empresa
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RegimeTributario { get; set; }             

        ...

        public ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos{ get; set; }
```

Porém ao tentar fazer um `POST` em `Cliente`, o  `JSON` gerado pela documentação do `Swagger` não fica da forma que eu gostaria que ficasse, ficando desta forma:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "pessoa": "string",
  "enderecos": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "cep": "string",
      "clientes": [
        null
      ],
      "empresas": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "regimeTributario": "string",
          "enderecos": [
            null
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Implementação:

```
public async Task<Cliente> Registro(Cliente cliente)
        {
            await _context.AddAsync(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return cliente;
        }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Registro([FromBody] Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (cliente != null)
            {
                await _clienteRep.Registro(cliente);
                return Ok(cliente);
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Ao testar no `Postman`, se eu edito esse `JSON` e mando somente os dados necessários, os mesmos são persistidos no banco de dados, mas há alguma maneira de fazer com que esse `JSON` usado no `POST` não tivesse dados da `Empresa`? Ou até mesmo uma maneira melhor de modelar esses relacionamentos.

Comment: `Clientes` e `Empresas` não deveriam ser `virtual` em `Endereço` ? Quando você se refere a um POST você não está querendo dizer um GET? Como você está recebendo?

Comment: Realmente não fui muito claro, estava me referindo ao `JSON` gerado na documentação do `Swagger`, o qual não fica como eu gostaria ao fazer um POST. E quanto a ser `virtual`, ainda não tenho muito conhecimento sobre isso, mas vou estudar sobre. Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: Quanto ao `swagger` o ideal é que sua camada da API trabalhe com `ViewModels` ou `DTOs` tanto para os `Requests` como para os `Responses`, assim você escreve esses objetos apenas com as propriedades necessárias e que deseja expor.